# Sql join исключить данные из результата

Tags: sql, join

Есть таблица событий t1 есть поле eid, есть таблица участников t2 с eid, uid (см. скрин)
[image: Таблица пользователи]

Все поля "int"

Задача вывести все события в которых нет юзера 3, запрос:

```
SELECT a.eid FROM t1 a 
JOIN t2 b ON a.eid=b.eid AND b.uid<>3 
GROUP BY a.eid
```

Выводит eid 1,2 и 3. Событие 2 в выдаче т.к. там есть и другие участники, и видимо "b.uid<>3" тут не помощник(

Пробовал получить все события юзера 3 и "отсеять результат", никакого эффекта

```
SELECT a.eid FROM t1 a 
JOIN t2 b ON a.eid=b.eid AND b.uid<>3 
JOIN (SELECT eid FROM t2 WHERE uid=3 GROUP BY eid) AS bb WHERE bb.eid<>b.eid
GROUP BY a.eid
```

Подскажите как исключить eid 2 из выдачи?

Comment: конечно, не совсем по теме, но хочу сказать, что названия колонок лучше делать event_id, user_id и делать их первичным ключом

Comment: @Alexxosipov Про первичный согласен. А вот почему лучше называть именно так как вы сказали, для меня загадка ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 вариант:

```
SELECT eid
  FROM t1
 WHERE eid NOT IN(select eid from t2 where uid=3)
```

2 вариант:

```
SELECT eid
  FROM t2
 GROUP BY eid
HAVING sum(case when uid=3 then 1 else 0 end)=0
```

3 вариант:

```
SELECT eid
  FROM t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from t2 where t1.eid=t2.eid and t2.uid=3)
```

4 вариант:

```
SELECT uid
  FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.eid=t2.eid and t2.uid=3
 WHERE t2.uid IS NULL
```

P.S. Во всех примерах предполагалось, что eid в таблице t1 уникален.

Comment: Mike, спасибо, первый вариант мне подходит.

Comment: @Роман Ну они все подходят в той или иной мере, по крайней мере должны давать одинаковый результат. Я их показал все специально, что бы во первых можно было выбрать, во вторых показать как широк этот выбор. При работе с SQL всегда лучше знать, что есть много подходов, потому что в каких то более сложных случаях, будет возможно применить только часть из них, а другие окажутся не приемлемыми в виду не нужного размножения записей, чрезмерного усложнения запроса или медленного выполнения.